# Joining multiple records in a CursorAdapter

Tags: android, join, adapter, android-cursor, android-cursoradapter

I'm trying to build a ListView that represents a list a recipes.  I get the concept of using a `SimpleCursorAdapter` to accomplish that.

However, in addition to showing the recipe image & title for each item, I'd like to show a comma-separated string of ingredients associated with the recipe.  Given that a cursor is only for one table (or view), I'm not quite sure how to approach this.

Relevant tables/columns are below:

```
recipes (
  _id integer primary key,
  name text not null
)

ingredients (
  _id integer primary key,
  name text not null
)

recipes_ingredients (
  _id integer primary key,
  recipe_id integer not null,
  ingredient_id integer not null
)
```

**Edit:** The first two comments on this question lead me to believe there's not enough information about why I think a simple JOIN won't suffice.  Given the table structure, a recipe can have *multiple* ingredients, not just one.  That means if I try to perform a join for a single recipe, I'll end up with something like the following:

```
SELECT r.name AS recipe, i.name AS ingredient
FROM recipes r
INNER JOIN recipes_ingredients ri ON ri.recipe_id=r._id
INNER JOIN ingredients i ON ri.ingredient_id=i._id;

 recipe           | ingredient
------------------+---------------------
 Chocolate Milk   | milk
 Chocolate Milk   | chocolate syrup
 Chicken Parmesan | chicken breast
 Chicken Parmesan | italian breadcrumbs
 Chicken Parmesan | egg
 Chicken Parmesan | shredded mozzarella
 Chicken Parmesan | pasta sauce
```

A simple cursor would end up showing "Chocolate Milk" twice and "Chicken Parmesan" five times.  This is definitely not what I want.  I want each of them to display **once** with all the ingredients comma-separated.  i.e.:

```
 recipe           | ingredients
------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Chocolate Milk   | milk, chocolate syrup
 Chicken Parmesan | chicken breast, italian breadcrumbs, egg, shredded mozzarella, pasta sauce
```

Comment: This page offers a good introduction to SQL JOIN and that's what you will need in this case: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: A `Cursor` is pretty much a wrapper around the result set returned by a database query. In other words: saying that a *"cursor is only for one table"*, is not true. You should change your query to include the ingredients data for every recipe. Basically you'll want to do a join and select columns from both the recipes and ingredients table.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin @MH - Okay, so can either of you provide an answer that shows how to join one `recipe` column to multiple `ingredient` columns and only have it be one result as a comma-delimited list of ingredients?  The way I see it, if I join recipes to ingredients, I'll end up with multiple rows for the same recipe instead of just one row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is group_concat: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html

This should work:

```
SELECT r._id, r.name AS recipe, group_concat(i.name, ",") AS ingredient
FROM recipes r
INNER JOIN recipes_ingredients ri ON ri.recipe_id=r._id
INNER JOIN ingredients i ON ri.ingredient_id=i._id
GROUP BY r._id;
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you!!  For reference, here's more info on it along with a way to specify the separator: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html